# Cannot open blob file on chrome v.71 ios 12+

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

Already used this code, cannot open the blob url in chrome ios, the result is just: **about:blank**.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var out = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
reader.onload = function(e){
       window.location.href = reader.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(out);
```

Also already tried using **FileSaver.js**, still cannot open it.

Any idea for this case/issue?

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution? I am currently having the same issue

Comment: still cannot find the resolution for this, i am still searching to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am occurring the same problem in a nearly close-phase project.
Very depressing that it blocks my project schedule..

However, i found that the Chrome IOS v71 is affecting the FileSaver and MIME type but still no idea how to solve it. I am going to explore the compatibility of FileReader

Comment: thanks Oscar, i still explore how to fix that case.
only happen on IOS Chrome.